# Weak convergence of Feller processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Let $Z^n=\{Z^n(s)\}_{s\geq 0}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $Z=\{Z(s)\}_{s\geq 0}$ be Feller processes on a complete separable  metric space $V$ ($\mathbb{R}^d$ for example).

Let $D[0,t]$ the Skorohod space of cadlag functions from $[0,t]$ to $V$.

Assume we know that, for any $0<t<\bar{t}$, $Z^n$ converges weakly to $Z$ in $D[0,t]$.

Since the processes are Feller, thus strongly continuous, I would guess that then
$Z^n$ converges weakly to $Z$ in $D[0,\bar{t}]$.
Is this true? I don't know how to prove this rigorously.